# Vaadin: NoClassDefFoundError on SubscriberExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, vaadin, noclassdeffounderror, event-bus

Attempting to implement the same sort of `Event` and `EventBus` stuff that's in the [Dashboard demo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo), I'm getting this error when I try to run the app:

```
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
Aug 31, 2015 3:06:08 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/eventbus/SubscriberExceptionHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at info.chrismcgee.sky.scheduling.SchedulingUI.<init>(SchedulingUI.java:48)
```

Line 48 in `SchedulingUI.java` is:

```
private final SchedulingEventBus schedulingEventbus = new SchedulingEventBus();
```

(I've mostly just replaced all the "Dashboard" references to "Scheduling" to conform with my web app.) Of course, it doesn't help that I am still trying to figure out the point of `SchedulingEvent.java` and `SchedulingEventBus.java` and how they work. (Still a newbie.)

**EDIT 09/01/2015:** For clarification about what I renamed, here is my `SchedulingEventBus.java` file:

```
package info.chrismcgee.sky.event;

import info.chrismcgee.sky.scheduling.SchedulingUI;

import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionContext;
import com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionHandler;

/**
 * A simple wrapper for Guava event bus. Defines static convenience methods for
 * relevant actions.
 * 
 * @author Marketing
 *
 */
public class SchedulingEventBus implements SubscriberExceptionHandler {

    private final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus(this);

    public static void post(final Object event) {
        SchedulingUI.getSchedulingEventbus().eventBus.post(event);
    }

    public static void register(final Object object) {
        SchedulingUI.getSchedulingEventbus().eventBus.register(object);
    }

    public static void unregister(final Object object) {
        SchedulingUI.getSchedulingEventbus().eventBus.unregister(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(final Throwable exception,
            final SubscriberExceptionContext context) {

        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: your SchedulingEventBus should implement the missing class (https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo/blob/d038b30c9463a630971626828682bf9ddec8b7b6/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/dashboard/event/DashboardEventBus.java#L12); is there everything i order?  errors in your ide? actually it's quite hard to tell, whats wrong here, if you use something (presumeably) working and change everything and give the only clue, that some name changed.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @cfrick. I'm not seeing a missing class that I need to implement, could you please help me to identify it? If you're referring to the `SubscriberEventHandler`, that should be included in the library with everything else related to `com.google.common.eventbus`. Regardless, I've added the entirety of my `SchedulingEventBus.java` file so you can see what I meant when I said that I replaced the word "Dashboard" with "Scheduling". Feel free to compare it to Vaadin's `DashboardEventBus.java` file on github.

Comment: then there is something wrong with the dependencies; google eventbus stuff is not in classpath ?

Comment: It should be; it's all a part of the Vaadin package, as far as I know. Sadly, no one on the Vaadin forums is responding to this problem.

Comment: has it ever worked? i'd bisect the problem then

Comment: No, it has never worked. This is my first time attempting to use `EventBus`. What do you mean by 'bisect' the problem?

Comment: then my best bet is, that you just don't have the deps in your classpath or you use some radical different version, that moved or renamed that class. *bisect* would mean, that if you have a working version and a failing one you could (binary) search for the culprit in between (e.g. `git bisect`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency to the ivy.xml file:

```
<dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="18.0"/>
```

I was having the exact same problem trying to do the exact same thing. This cleared up the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: That seems to have solved it! Thanks a million, @Jennie!